# Parent child relationship with protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols, parent-child

I'm trying to describe parent child model with protocols in Swift 3.

```
protocol CatalogFilter: class {

    var title: String { get }

    associatedtype FilterItem: CatalogFilterItem
    var items: [FilterItem] { get }

}

protocol CatalogFilterItem: class {

    associatedtype Filter: CatalogFilter
    var filter: Filter? { get }

    var title: String { get }

}
```

But I get an error `type may not reference itself as a requirement
    associatedtype FilterItem: CatalogFilterItem` for `associatedtype FilterItem: CatalogFilterItem` and the same error for `associatedtype Filter: CatalogFilter`

Maybe someone knows how to handle such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protocol CatalogFilter: class {

   var title: String { get }

   associatedtype CatalogFilterItem
   var items: [CatalogFilterItem] { get }

}

protocol CatalogFilterItem: class {

  associatedtype Filter: CatalogFilter

  var filter: Filter? { get }
  var title: String { get }

}
```

Try the above as it looks like the support for recursive constraints on associated types are still not available.

Ref- https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0157-recursive-protocol-constraints.md